# dovecot socket not found running as service

Tags: dovecot, socket, debian-stretch

I got a strange problem concerning dovecot.
My dovecot was working flawlessly on my cubietruck until yesterday, when I upgraded from debian/jessie to debian/stretch (armhf).
`/var` is symlinked to another mounted drive (mountpoint `/extended`): `/var` -> `/extended/hostname/var`

Now whenever I start it as service ("`systemctl start dovecot`"), it does not start but exits immediately with error.

```
May 08 21:16:20 hostname systemd[1]: Starting Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server...
May 08 21:16:20 hostname dovecot[32167]: Error: bind(/var/spool/postfix/private/auth_dovecot) failed: No such file or directory
May 08 21:16:20 hostname dovecot[32167]: Fatal: Failed to start listeners
May 08 21:16:20 hostname systemd[1]: dovecot.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=89
May 08 21:16:20 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
May 08 21:16:20 hostname systemd[1]: dovecot.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 08 21:16:20 hostname systemd[1]: dovecot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Whenever I start dovecot as `root` in shell by `dovecot` it does not show any error but works flawlessly.

my `dovecot.conf`:

```
auth_mechanisms = plain login
log_timestamp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-mysql.conf
  driver = sql
}
protocols = imap pop3
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth_dovecot {
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-master {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
  user = root
}
ssl_cert =</etc/postfix/sslcert/server.crt
ssl_key =</etc/postfix/sslcert/server.key
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-mysql.conf
  driver = sql
}
protocol pop3 {
  pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv
}

# Enable installed protocols
!include_try /usr/share/dovecot/protocols.d/*.protocol

# Most of the actual configuration gets included below. The filenames are
# first sorted by their ASCII value and parsed in that order. The 00-prefixes
# in filenames are intended to make it easier to understand the ordering.
!include conf.d/*.conf

# A config file can also tried to be included without giving an error if
# ried not found:
!include_try local.conf
```

- I already deleted the socket `/var/spool/postfix/private/auth_dovecot` before start, but no avail when started as service.  When started in shell the socket (`auth_dovecot`) is recreated on start.
- Commenting out the `unix_listener`-part leads to possibly timeout on start. The error reads `PID file /var/run/dovecot/master.pid not readable (yet?) after start`.
- Using another name for the socket (`/var/spool/postfix/private/auth`) leads to same error.
- I already tried to reinstall dovecot completely (apt purge, autoremove, autoclean, clean, install, ...), but that leads to timeout problems and strange config files.
- searching on google/stackexchange doesn't bring up a solution.

Because I can run dovecot without problems as root from shell, I strongly suspect `systemd` generating some sort of `chroot` but I need some hints to further investigate it.

Thank you in advance.

PS: Fortunately I should be able to go back to `debian/jessie` since I have an `tar.gz`-archive of the `cubietruck` SD-card.

Comment: Would the upgrade have activated SELinux?

Comment: Doesn't seem so. Only "libselinux" is installed, no other selinux related packages. "getenforce" or "sestatus" are not available on the machine.
I don't know selinux, so where else to look at, whether it's activated or disturbing my dovecot?

Comment: Changing the default locations/paths of a product is something that SELinux would prevent.  And I had the impression your problem had to do with permissions eg. (starting as root works). Be sure to check if dovecot has the necessary permissions on /var/spool/postfix.

Comment: What filesystem is /extended?

Comment: /extended is ext4.
I found a solution after doing a relatively clean upgrade from my jessie backup to stretch.

Comment: Always keep it as clean as possible, your Smelliness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some strange behaviour regarding `systemd`.

I solved it by editing the `postfix.service` file (`/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dovecot.service`) and set the default entry `PrivateTmp=true` to `PrivateTmp=false`.

```
# This file is part of Dovecot
#
# If you want to pass additionally command line options to the dovecot
# binary, create the file:
#   `/etc/systemd/system/dovecot.service.d/service.conf'.
# In this file create a Service section and configure an Environment with
# the variable `OPTIONS'. For example:
#
#   [Service]
#   Environment='OPTIONS=-p'
#
# In the `Service' section you may also specify various other setting.
# If you have trouble with `Too many open files' you may set:
#LimitNOFILE=8192
#
# If you want to allow the Dovecot services to produce core dumps, use:
#LimitCORE=infinity

[Unit]
Description=Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server
Documentation=man:dovecot(1)
Documentation=http://wiki2.dovecot.org/
After=local-fs.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dovecot
PIDFile=/var/run/dovecot/master.pid
ExecReload=/usr/bin/doveadm reload
ExecStop=/usr/bin/doveadm stop
PrivateTmp=false
NonBlocking=yes
# Enable this if your systemd is new enough to support it:
#ProtectSystem=off
```

The reason why a config parameter named `PrivateTmp` is not only working on the documented folders `/tmp` or `/var/tmp` but also blocks access to `/var/spool` (or `/var/spool/postfix/private/auth_dovecot`) content is not clear to me.